# How to detect if a tun/tap device already exists

Tags: c, linux, tun

I want to create a tun device with the code, so before creating it I want to check if the tun device already exists

Right now I'm doing this by determining if the file already exists, but this method is not graceful

Is there a better way

```
    char tun_dev_name[IFNAMSIZ + 15];
    for(int tun_num = 0; ;tun_num++)
    {
        sprintf(ifr.ifr_name, "tun%d", tun_num);
        //TODO it is not graceful
        sprintf(tun_dev_name, "/sys/class/net/%s", ifr.ifr_name);
        if(access(tun_dev_name, F_OK) != 0 )
            break;
    }
```

Comment: can't you pass %d in the interface name to the kernel, and the kernel chooses a number for you?

Comment: @user253751 I never thought I could do that. Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask the kernel for an interface name with a `%d` in it, the kernel will choose a number for you and you won't need to do this.

See [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) which includes an example program with this comment:

> char *dev should be the name of the device with a format string (e.g. "tun%d"), but (as far as I can see) this can be any valid network device name.
> Note that the character pointer becomes overwritten with the real device name (e.g. "tun0")

As the comment says, after you execute `TUNSETIFF` to set the interface name with a format string, the buffer is overwritten with the name the kernel selected. Make sure it's large enough - `IFNAMSIZ` bytes including null terminator.